# How to download bulk amount of images from google or any website

Tags: python-3.x

actually, I need to do a project on machine learning. In that I want a lot of images for training. I searched for this problem, but I failed to do so.
can anyone help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't the problem not getting pictures, but establishing ground truths? For each picture you need to draw a bounding box (or multiple ones) and describe each object. If you are making a general classifier, there are a number of [pre-labeled deep learning data sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_datasets_for_machine_learning_research).

Comment: Yeah...first I will download one class(0) then another class(1) then I will dump them into pickle in order. then I will make array with 0's and 1's in order(Binary Classification)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used google images to download images using selenium. It is just a basic approach.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import urllib.request
import os
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome("path\\to\\the\\webdriverFile") 
browser.get("https://www.google.com")

search = browser.find_element_by_name(‘q’)

search.send_keys(key_words,Keys.ENTER) # use required key_words to download images
elem = browser.find_element_by_link_text(‘Images’)
elem.get_attribute(‘href’)
elem.click()
value = 0
for i in range(20):
    browser.execute_script(“scrollBy(“+ str(value) +”,+1000);”)
    value += 1000
    time.sleep(3)
elem1 = browser.find_element_by_id(‘islmp’)
sub = elem1.find_elements_by_tag_name(“img”)
try:
    os.mkdir(‘downloads’)
except FileExistsError:
    pass
count = 0
for i in sub:
    src = i.get_attribute('src')
    try:
        if src != None:
            src  = str(src)
            print(src)
            count+=1
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(src, 
os.path.join('downloads','image'+str(count)+'.jpg'))
        else:
            raise TypeError
    except TypeError:
        print('fail')
    if count == required_images_number: ## use number as required
        break
```

[check this](https://medium.com/@divya.reddy19/download-images-from-google-using-python-20d6588fc3f1) for detailed explanation.

download driver [here](https://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/)

Answer (score 0):

My tip to you is: Use pictures API. This is my favourite: [Bing Image Search API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-image-search/)

Following text from [Send search queries using the REST API and Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-image-search/quickstarts/python).

## Running the quickstart

To get started, set subscription_key to a valid subscription key for the Bing API service.

**Python**

```
subscription_key = None
assert subscription_key
```

Next, verify that the search_url endpoint is correct. At this writing, only one endpoint is used for Bing search APIs. If you encounter authorization errors, double-check this value against the Bing search endpoint in your Azure dashboard.
Python

```
search_url = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/images/search"
```

Set search_term to look for images of puppies.
Python

```
search_term = "puppies"
```

The following block uses the requests library in Python to call out to the Bing search APIs and return the results as a JSON object. Observe that we pass in the API key via the headers dictionary and the search term via the params dictionary. To see the full list of options that can be used to filter search results, refer to the REST API documentation.

**Python**

```
import requests

headers = {"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" : subscription_key}
params  = {"q": search_term, "license": "public", "imageType": "photo"}
response = requests.get(search_url, headers=headers, params=params)
response.raise_for_status()
search_results = response.json()
```

The search_results object contains the actual images along with rich metadata such as related items. For example, the following line of code can extract the thumbnail URLS for the first 16 results.
Python

```
thumbnail_urls = [img["thumbnailUrl"] for img in search_results["value"][:16]]
```

Then use the PIL library to download the thumbnail images and the matplotlib library to render them on a $4 \times 4$ grid.

**Python**

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

f, axes = plt.subplots(4, 4)
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        image_data = requests.get(thumbnail_urls[i+4*j])
        image_data.raise_for_status()
        image = Image.open(BytesIO(image_data.content))        
        axes[i][j].imshow(image)
        axes[i][j].axis("off")
plt.show()
```

## Sample JSON response

Responses from the Bing Image Search API are returned as JSON. This sample response has been truncated to show a single result.

**JSON**

```
{
"_type":"Images",
"instrumentation":{
    "_type":"ResponseInstrumentation"
},
"readLink":"images\/search?q=tropical ocean",
"webSearchUrl":"https:\/\/www.bing.com\/images\/search?q=tropical ocean&FORM=OIIARP",
"totalEstimatedMatches":842,
"nextOffset":47,
"value":[
    {
        "webSearchUrl":"https:\/\/www.bing.com\/images\/search?view=detailv2&FORM=OIIRPO&q=tropical+ocean&id=8607ACDACB243BDEA7E1EF78127DA931E680E3A5&simid=608027248313960152",
        "name":"My Life in the Ocean | The greatest WordPress.com site in ...",
        "thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/tse3.mm.bing.net\/th?id=OIP.fmwSKKmKpmZtJiBDps1kLAHaEo&pid=Api",
        "datePublished":"2017-11-03T08:51:00.0000000Z",
        "contentUrl":"https:\/\/mylifeintheocean.files.wordpress.com\/2012\/11\/tropical-ocean-wallpaper-1920x12003.jpg",
        "hostPageUrl":"https:\/\/mylifeintheocean.wordpress.com\/",
        "contentSize":"897388 B",
        "encodingFormat":"jpeg",
        "hostPageDisplayUrl":"https:\/\/mylifeintheocean.wordpress.com",
        "width":1920,
        "height":1200,
        "thumbnail":{
        "width":474,
        "height":296
        },
        "imageInsightsToken":"ccid_fmwSKKmK*mid_8607ACDACB243BDEA7E1EF78127DA931E680E3A5*simid_608027248313960152*thid_OIP.fmwSKKmKpmZtJiBDps1kLAHaEo",
        "insightsMetadata":{
        "recipeSourcesCount":0,
        "bestRepresentativeQuery":{
            "text":"Tropical Beaches Desktop Wallpaper",
            "displayText":"Tropical Beaches Desktop Wallpaper",
            "webSearchUrl":"https:\/\/www.bing.com\/images\/search?q=Tropical+Beaches+Desktop+Wallpaper&id=8607ACDACB243BDEA7E1EF78127DA931E680E3A5&FORM=IDBQDM"
        },
        "pagesIncludingCount":115,
        "availableSizesCount":44
        },
        "imageId":"8607ACDACB243BDEA7E1EF78127DA931E680E3A5",
        "accentColor":"0050B2"
    }
}
```

Comment: you need a subscription key

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/try/cognitive-services/?api=bing-web-search-api

Comment: getting access denied. How to fix it